# Person Account Feature Activation

Tags: sandbox, person-accounts

Let's assume that person account feature in my production org has been enabled. Do I have to log another case to enable it on my sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refresh the sandbox or create a new one then the Configuration including person accounts will be enable with the org.

If you have an existing sandbox and do not wish to refresh it, then yes you would have to log a case